# Drupal Commerce Product Pricing Rules disapear

Tags: commerce, rules

When I add a new rule in Product Pricing rules they disappear out of the Product Pricing Rules Window. They are still available in Workflow->Rules.

I am also finding that it seems to be hit and miss weather I am able to access all data on the system. Sometimes the rule I create sticks in the Product Pricing Rules window for a few minutes and those rules when created give full access to all referenced data. But I create a new rule and cant see data that I know I should be able to I know then that this is going to be one of the rules that will disapear into the Workflow->rules window.

Any idea what is happening.

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like for some reason the event is getting removed or changed to something other than "Calculating the price of a product." However, without seeing a screenshot of your Rules list, there's no way to tell. Look at the list and see what the event is getting set to.

If you use the product pricing rule add link from the product pricing interface, it should be altering the form to pre-select the proper event and hide the select list. Perhaps you have some other code on the site that undoes that selection or otherwise invalidates it.